# Exporting the data about angles from STK

Tags: raw-data, stk-agi, solar-panel

I recently started learning how to use STK, I was wondering how I would export data for the angles of the solar panels into something like a spreadsheet. I can easily do this with values like effective area and power but for angles, it lists it separately for every single minute. Does anyone know how I could export all of the data in a spreadsheet?

Another question, is it possible to disable some of the solar panels, I am using the 6U cube satellite and in our actual model we only have solar panels on the two biggest sides. Would this be possible to have it so only the solar panels on the two biggest sides generate power or would I need to create my own satellite model?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly which report you are trying to export?